# Can't monitor Dropbox folder

Tags: debian, inotify, dropbox

I recently installed Dropbox on my computer running Debian 9.3. But it will not sync. When I mouse over the icon in the notification area of my toolbar, a message says...

```
Can't monitor Dropbox folder (Click to fix)
Can't access Dropbox folder
```

When I click the icon, the menu comes up, and I click "Can't monitor Dropbox folder (Click to fix)."

But when I do, a window pops up that says "Type your Linux password to let Dropbox make changes." It also asks if I'd like to save this password to my keyring. When I type my regular login password, the window says it is the incorrect password.

My designated Dropbox folder is on an HDD while Debian 9 is installed on an SSD.

How do I allow Dropbox program to access Dropbox folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this AU Q&A titled: [How do I fix a “Can't access Dropbox folder” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247461/how-do-i-fix-a-cant-access-dropbox-folder-error) it sounds like you could try these to see if they resolve your issue:

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

If you find this resolves it you can make these permanent. Add the following to this file:

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/99-dropbox.conf
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 1048576
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 256
```

Then run this to pick up the changes:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: This only work for smaller folders... When they increase you are doomed... Nothing will help because when fs.inotify.max_user_instances = fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 999999999 that is your max... After that you are doomed. Dropbox doesn't work anymore... It happened to me...